# how to fix git apply error: src/actions/__tests__/actions.test.tsx: No such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, git, typescript, redux, patch

I am at branch which is `my-branch`, nothing to commit, working tree clean. I ran the command `git format-patch master --stdout > my-name.patch`

I checked out to `master` branch. Then ran the command
`git apply --check my-name.patch`

I got below error:

```
error: src/actions/__tests__/actions.test.tsx: No such file or directory
```

I do have the `src/actions/__tests__` directory and I have the `actions.test.tsx` file in it. If I run yarn test, I can see the `actions.test.tsx`file runs and pass the tests. I recreated the directory and file several times, still got the same error.

How can I fix the problem? I've tried different ways to solve the problem, but nothing was working.